# Como divido un String en javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Hola si tengo un string por ejemplo "hola esto es un ejemplo" puede ser cualquier cosa, como hago para dividir el string a partir del primer espacio, es decir como obtengo "esto es un ejemplo"
Intente con `split(" ")[1]`  pero obtengo "esto"

Comment: Puedes utilizar la funcion `indexOf` para encontrar la primera coincidencia de un espacio y despues utilizar `substring`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Retomando lo mencionado en los comentarios, aqui te dejo un breve ejemplo de como utilizarlo.

```js
var stx="hola este es un ejemplo";

var otra = stx.substring(stx.indexOf(' ') + 1 ,stx.length) ;
console.log(otra);
```

El `+ 1` es para obviar el espacio en blanco que queda al principio de la cadena.

Answer (score 3):

Otra alternativa poca ortodoxa es aplicar un split y recorrer el array concatenando cada uno de los item obviando el primer elemento del array:

```
const stx = 'hola esto es un ejemplo';
const arrStx = stx.split(' ');
let cnt = 0;
let solve = '';

arrStx.forEach( elemen => {
    if ( cnt >= 1 ) {
        if ( cnt !== 1 ) {
            solve += ' ';
        }
        solve += elemen;
    }
    cnt++;
});

console.log(solve);
```